# Flash videos show up black on most pages

Tags: windows-7, flash-player, adobe-flash

I've got trouble with Flash Player on Windows 7 x64. The latest player is installed.

Videos won't play back on most pages (like thedailyshow.com or southpark.de). Other pages like YouTube work.

I already tried IE 8, Firefox 4 and the latest Chrome (which comes with its own Flash plugin).

What may be the cause of that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not only what was mentioned above, but you may be using the 64bit version of IE8. Flash is not supported on the 64bit browsers yet. Have you tried running it in the 32 bit version of IE8?

Answer (score 0):

The reason videos work on YouTube and not other sites is that it's possible you're in the test market for YouTube HTML5 specifications to display videos instead of flash.

As for the cause, a co-worker of mine had various graphical type issues that turned out to be related to his unlocking extra cores in his processor. It was an AMD processor advertised as dual core, but actually had 2 additional cores locked, but making changes on the motherboard (similar to overclocking, but difference changes) the additional cores were unlocked causing the problems. After resetting the motherboard processor settings his graphical issues vanished.